# python tkinter draw random number

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, random, text

I need to put a random number as the speed limit in my max speed sign.

Here´s my code:

```
from random import *
canvas= tkinter.Canvas (bg="white" , height = "1000", width ="1000")
canvas.pack()


x=randint(100,900)
y=randint(100,900)
speed=randint (30,80)


canvas.create_oval(x-100, y-100, x+100,y+100, fill="firebrick3", width="2")
canvas.create_oval(x-75, y-75, x+75,y+75, fill="white", width="2")
canvas.create_text(x,y, text=" I NEED HELP HERE ", font="Calibri 20 bold")
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to be outputted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from random import *
canvas= tkinter.Canvas (bg="white" , height = "1000", width ="1000")
canvas.pack()


x=randint(100,900)
y=randint(100,900)
speed=randint(30,80)


canvas.create_oval(x-100, y-100, x+100,y+100, fill="firebrick3", width="2")
canvas.create_oval(x-75, y-75, x+75,y+75, fill="white", width="2")
canvas.create_text(x,y, text=str(speed), font="Calibri 20 bold")
```

All I did was change the text on the canvas to the speed variable that you already defined. I'm not 100% sure if it has to be a string when it is asking for text but i changed it anyways. This should work, let me know if it doesn't.